# Org-mode custom youtube link syntax

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I would like to define a custom `org-mode` link, which accepts the following syntax:

`[[yt:<video ID>]]`

and produces an image link equivalent to this:

```
[[https://youtu.be/<video ID>][http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video ID>/0.jpg]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It is simple to produce a link equivalently to `[[https://youtu.be/<video ID>]]` with `org-link-set-parameters`. But, it is hard to create something that is equivalent to an image link. Currently, I believe that would involve setting up extra font-lock rules.

Comment: Yasnippet might help?

Comment: @mankoff I think the OP does not want to change the link text but he wants orgmode to **interpret** the link text `[[yt:<video ID>]]` as image link to the youtube-url. I assume the phrases "define a custom org-mode link" and "equivalent" actually mean that.

Comment: I actually tested this and images links of the form `[[https://youtu.be/<video ID>][http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video ID>/0.jpg]]` work in org 9.0! So really I'm just looking for a way to simplify this with a syntax like `[[yt:<video ID>]]`.

Comment: It is clear that the links `[[...][...]]` with url and description work. If you accept that your simplified links are automagically replaced by the long version you can go with @makoff's proposal. If you want to keep your simplified links then `org-set-link-parameters` is the way to go. The parameter `org-link-paramters` allows for an option `:activate-func` for its entries. I think that is the hook where one can put an overlay with the image as `display` property on the link.

Comment: With respect to my last comment it turned out that `:activate-func` is not the right place to add the image conversation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The abbreviated link type can easily be defined with `org-set-link-parameters`. That handles url's like `yt:<video ID>` but not image overlays for org links like `[[https://youtu.be/<video ID>][http://img.youtube.com/vi/<video ID>/0.jpg]]`.

The regular expression for image overlays is hard-coded in `org-display-inline-images`.

Thus you need to add the generation of the image overlays for `yt` links to that function. One way to do that is an `:after`-advice.

One can re-use a large part of `org-display-inline-images` for that job. Best was a refactoring of `org-display-inline-images`. (This function should definitively be split into several functions.) But, that would be a task for the org-devs.

I've taken a section out of `org-display-inline-images` to do the job.
You can copy that stuff into your [init-file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), restart emacs and voila you get what you ask for.

This is a simple variant. Maybe, one could add file-caching for the retrieved youtube-images.

```el
(require 'org)
(require 'org-element)

(defcustom org-yt-url-protocol "yt"
  "Protocol identifier for youtube links."
  :group 'org-yt
  :type 'string)

(defun org-yt-follow (video-id)
  "Open youtube with VIDEO-ID."
  (browse-url (concat "https://youtu.be/" video-id)))

(org-link-set-parameters org-yt-url-protocol :follow #'org-yt-follow)

(defun org-image-update-overlay (file link &optional data-p refresh)
  "Create image overlay for FILE associtated with org-element LINK.
        If DATA-P is non-nil FILE is not a file name but a string with the image data.
        See also `create-image'.
        This function is almost a duplicate of a part of `org-display-inline-images'."
  (when (or data-p (file-exists-p file))
    (let ((width
           ;; Apply `org-image-actual-width' specifications.
           (cond
            ((not (image-type-available-p 'imagemagick)) nil)
            ((eq org-image-actual-width t) nil)
            ((listp org-image-actual-width)
             (or
              ;; First try to find a width among
              ;; attributes associated to the paragraph
              ;; containing link.
              (let ((paragraph
                     (let ((e link))
                       (while (and (setq e (org-element-property
                                            :parent e))
                                   (not (eq (org-element-type e)
                                            'paragraph))))
                       e)))
                (when paragraph
                  (save-excursion
                    (goto-char (org-element-property :begin paragraph))
                    (when
                        (re-search-forward
                         "^[ \t]*#\\+attr_.*?: +.*?:width +\\(\\S-+\\)"
                         (org-element-property
                          :post-affiliated paragraph)
                         t)
                      (string-to-number (match-string 1))))))
              ;; Otherwise, fall-back to provided number.
              (car org-image-actual-width)))
            ((numberp org-image-actual-width)
             org-image-actual-width)))
          (old (get-char-property-and-overlay
                (org-element-property :begin link)
                'org-image-overlay)))
      (if (and (car-safe old) refresh)
          (image-refresh (overlay-get (cdr old) 'display))
        (let ((image (create-image file
                                   (and width 'imagemagick)
                                   data-p
                                   :width width)))
          (when image
            (let* ((link
                    ;; If inline image is the description
                    ;; of another link, be sure to
                    ;; consider the latter as the one to
                    ;; apply the overlay on.
                    (let ((parent
                           (org-element-property :parent link)))
                      (if (eq (org-element-type parent) 'link)
                          parent
                        link)))
                   (ov (make-overlay
                        (org-element-property :begin link)
                        (progn
                          (goto-char
                           (org-element-property :end link))
                          (skip-chars-backward " \t")
                          (point)))))
              (overlay-put ov 'display image)
              (overlay-put ov 'face 'default)
              (overlay-put ov 'org-image-overlay t)
              (overlay-put
               ov 'modification-hooks
               (list 'org-display-inline-remove-overlay))
              (push ov org-inline-image-overlays))))))))

(defun org-yt-get-image (url)
  "Retrieve image from url."
  (let ((image-buf (url-retrieve-synchronously url)))
    (when image-buf
      (with-current-buffer image-buf
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (when (looking-at "HTTP/")
          (delete-region (point-min)
                         (progn (re-search-forward "\n[\n]+")
                                (point))))
        (setq image-data (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))))

(defconst org-yt-video-id-regexp "[-_[:alnum:]]\\{10\\}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]"
  "Regexp matching youtube video id's taken from `https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54443/format-for-id-of-youtube-video'.")

(defun org-yt-display-inline-images (&optional include-linked refresh beg end)
  "Like `org-display-inline-images' but for yt-links."
  (when (display-graphic-p)
    (org-with-wide-buffer
     (goto-char (or beg (point-min)))
     (let ((re (format "\\[\\[%s:\\(%s\\)\\]\\]" org-yt-url-protocol org-yt-video-id-regexp)))
       (while (re-search-forward re end t)
         (let ((video-id (match-string 1))
               (el (save-excursion (goto-char (match-beginning 1)) (org-element-context)))
               image-data)
           (when el
             (setq image-data 
                   (or (let ((old (get-char-property-and-overlay
                                   (org-element-property :begin el)
                                   'org-image-overlay)))
                         (and old
                              (car-safe old)
                              (overlay-get (cdr old) 'display)))
                       (org-yt-get-image (format "http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/0.jpg" video-id))))
             (when image-data
               (org-image-update-overlay image-data el t t)))))))))

(advice-add #'org-display-inline-images :after #'org-yt-display-inline-images)
```

Test environment:

- emacs version 25.3.1
- org-mode version 9.0.9 (installed from `melpa`), (also works with version 9.1.6)

Test:

- Start emacs with `emacs -Q`
- Run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-initialize` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Copy above code to the `*scratch*` buffer
- Call there <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Call <kbd>C-x b</kbd> `test.org` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Insert following org code into that buffer

  ```org
  [[yt:papuvlVeZg8]]

  [[yt:_ha3o-YcnhA]]

  [[yt:s43sptuwkvA]]

  [[yt:cxjvTXo9WWM]]

  [[yt:W6e1TctNyw8]]
  ```
- Call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org-display-inline-images` <kbd>RET</kbd> (that is also needed for standard inline images)

Comment: Wow -Thanks Tobias! I am testing this out with the video ID `_ha3o-YcnhA` but it doesn't seem to be working... perhaps a problem with the regex?

Comment: @Adam Please, try again.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm entering the link `[[yt:_ha3o-YcnhA]]` but no luck yet...

Comment: @Adam I've added a test recipe that works for me.

Comment: Ah, it works! @Tobias you are a star!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Adam I've added the display of the optional link description in the git-version of the code: https://github.com/TobiasZawada/org-yt

Comment: Ah, great idea! I look forward to seeing how this project develops. Maybe in the future, there could be a option to download videos and store them in a local Video folder? There's a fantastic command-line tool called youtube-dl that can grab content from pretty-much anywhere (not just youtube).